# changing Area Codes without rebuilding solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, asp.net-mvc-areas

I used **Areas** in my MVC5 projects. so i have to Rebuild my solution every time that i change Area Codes.

but we saw some projects like **orchard CMS** which don't need any clean and build operation on their solution when you change code of their modules(in fact,orchard modules are **mvc-Areas**).

how can they do it? which Technique or technology must i use to have a same thing in my  solution?

Answer (score 1):

The technology is called *Dynamic Compilation*.

Orchard is using it in a bit special way, but the documentation definitely worth a look: [Orchard Dynamic Compilation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation/)

Also you should check: [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)